# Re-routing VOIP packets from multiple ports to one specific port in rooted android phone

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, firewall, root-access

Suppose you have a rooted android phone.You are working on VOIP call application. How can you re-route packets coming from one specific IP address from multiple ports to one specific port.
Example:I need to re-route packets from IP address 10.2.3.4 from multiple ports like 200,300,400 to one specific port 450 without using middleware server.
Can you use firewall?

Comment: Show examples of the work you have done

Comment: Not an actual project.This question was asked for an interview of android dev.WANT TO KNOW IF THERE IS A WAY TO DO THIS....did a lot of research but didn't got an answer.